# EF 4.3.1 - code first automatic migrations - how to specify column width

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

I am trying to find examples or documentation related to DbMigration and ColumnModel.
I simply want to specify width of string propery in DBMigration Up method
E.g.

```
AddColumn("Districts", "Code", c => c.String());
```

will create nvarchar(max) - and I want to specify maxlength(20) for example.
Is this integrated with  EntityTypeConfiguration or I have to add also manually

```
this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Code").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
```

MSDN help doesn't give any examples and walkthrough on ef4 blog covers only basics

Answer (score 4):

If you use `AddColumn` directly you can simply use:

```
AddColumn("Districts", "Code", c => c.String(maxLength: 20));
```

If you define max length in `EntityTypeConfiguration` (which is correct approach) EF Migration will handle it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The configuration of the columns should be done as data annotations. To make a string column have a specific width, use the `StringLengthAttribute`:

```
[Required] // Makes column not null
[StringLength(20)] // Makes it a nvarchar(20) instead of nvarchar(max)
public string SomeString {get;set;}
```